# How to select graphics card while using opencv3 with opencl?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

My laptop has two graphics cards, Intel HD Graphics 530 and Nvidia Geforce GTX 965M. 
When I was using opencv3 with opencl, it automatically chose Intel. 
For faster speed, I want to use Nvidia instead.
I tried adding

```
OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE = NVIDIA:GPU:GTX 965M
```

to environment variables, but it didn't work.
Environments:
Windows 10, OpenCV 3.4.5, Cuda 9.2, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: People here are so allergic to "it didn't work" that you might be asked to clarify - even though in this case it seems quite obvious what you mean.

Comment: Try shorter case: OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE = NVIDIA:GPU:

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/59115/opencv-30-beta-and-opencl-setdevice/

Comment: Thanks buddies, after referring to http://answers.opencv.org/question/108646/opencl-can-not-detect-my-nvidia-gpu-via-opencv/ and rebooting, I got this problem solved. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

For driver version 302 or higher (which should be available on most systems, since the current version is >400) you have to export the global variable `NvOptimusEnablement`.

```
extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

Source: [This driver technical notes from NVIDIA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf) (page 3)